# Change default permission of device files

Tags: linux, permissions, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, udev

I have written my gpio driver and register it with the system using udev. This created all my device files but the permission they are created is 600. how can I change this default permission to 666 or any other. Since I have to run my program reading this file using sudo.

Should i write any rules in udev.. please explain.
Or should i change operating permission of my program within my program itself to root.

---

#### Update: my udev rules.d contains

**`40-scratch.rules`:**

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0694", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0003", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

**and `99-input.rules`:**

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input", GROUP="input", MODE="0660"
```

**and `udev.conf`:**

```
udev_log="err"
```

Comment: its best to add the udev rule in the post for others to review it.

Comment: @askb added the necessary info.